# Kalman filter, Local level model

Tags: time-series, self-study, kalman-filter

My question is regarding some calculations in the lecture notes “[State-Space Models and Kalman Filters](http://faculty.chicagobooth.edu/ruey.tsay/teaching/mts/sp2013/lec10-13.pdf)” by Ruey Tsay.

In the local level model we have (p. 1): $$y_{t}=\mu_{t}+e_{t},\; e_{t}\sim N\left(0,\:\sigma_{e}^{2}\right)
 $$ and $$\mu_{t+1}=\mu_{t}+\eta_{t},\; \eta_{t}\sim N\left(0,\:\sigma_{\eta}^{2}\right)
 $$.

Let (p. 3) $$F_{t-1}=\left\{ y_{1},\, y_{2},\, y_{3},\,\ldots,\, y_{t}\right\} 
 $$
$$y_{t\mid t-1}=E\left(y_{t}\left|F_{t-1}\right.\right)=E\left(\mu_{t}+e_{t}\left|F_{t-1}\right.\right)=E\left(\mu_{t}\left|F_{t-1}\right.\right)=\mu_{t\mid t-1}
 $$ and $$v_{t}=y_{t}-y_{t\mid t-1}=y_{t}-\mu_{t\mid t-1}
 $$. Further, $$Var\left(\mu_{t}\left|F_{j}\right.\right)=\sum_{t\mid j}
 $$

Then Tsay finds on p. 4: $$Cov\left(\mu_{t},\, v_{t}\left|F_{t-1}\right.\right) \\=E\left(\mu_{t}v_{t}\left|F_{t-1}\right.\right)\\
 =E\left(\mu_{t}\left(y_{t}-\mu_{t\mid t-1}\right)\left|F_{t-1}\right.\right)\\
 =E\left(\mu_{t}\left(\mu_{t}+e_{t}-\mu_{t\mid t-1}\right)\left|F_{t-1}\right.\right)\\
 =E\left(\mu_{t}\left(\mu_{t}-\mu_{t\mid t-1}\right)\left|F_{t-1}\right.\right)+E\left(\mu_{t}e_{t}\left|F_{t-1}\right.\right)\\
 =E\left(\left(\mu_{t}-\mu_{t\mid t-1}\right)^{2}\left|F_{t-1}\right.\right)\\
 =Var\left(u_{t}\left|F_{t-1}\right.\right)\\
 =\sum_{t\mid t-1}
 $$

and notes: Where we have used the fact that $$E\left(\mu_{t\mid t-1}\left(\mu_{t}-\mu_{t\mid t-1}\right)\left|F_{t-1}\right.\right)=0$$ (Eq. 2).

I am a bit confused over what is going on from the $4^{th}
 $ equality sign to the $5^{th}
 $ equality sign. When I multiply the parenthesis' out I get: $$E\left(\mu_{t}^{2}\left|F_{t-1}\right.\right)=\sum_{t\mid t-1}
 $$.

To complicate things further, Tsay shows in his book, [Analysis of Financial Time Series](http://www.math.zju.edu.cn/webpagenew/UploadFiles/AttachFiles/2015511135747313.pdf), p. 495 (2nd ed.) the following: $$Cov\left(\mu_{t},\, v_{t}\left|F_{t-1}\right.\right)\\ =E\left(\mu_{t}v_{t}\left|F_{t-1}\right.\right)\\
 =E\left(\mu_{t}\left(y_{t}-\mu_{t\mid t-1}\right)\left|F_{t-1}\right.\right)\\
 =E\left(\mu_{t}\left(\mu_{t}+e_{t}-\mu_{t\mid t-1}\right)\left|F_{t-1}\right.\right)\\
 =E\left(\mu_{t}\left(\mu_{t}-\mu_{t\mid t-1}\right)\left|F_{t-1}\right.\right)+E\left(\mu_{t}e_{t}\left|F_{t-1}\right.\right)\\
 =E\left(\left(\mu_{t}-\mu_{t\mid t-1}\right)^{2}\left|F_{t-1}\right.\right)\\
 =Var\left(\mu_{t}\left|F_{t-1}\right.\right)\\
 =\sum_{t\mid t-1}
 $$

In his book he does not use $u_{t}
 $ but $\mu_{t}
 $ in the $2^{nd}
 $ last equality sign. Again he notes that he has used: $$E\left(\mu_{t\mid t-1}\left(\mu_{t}-\mu_{t\mid t-1}\right)\left|F_{t-1}\right.\right)=0$$ (Eq. 2).

My question is: What am I missing here and what is going on from the $4^{th}
 $ equality sign to the $5^{th}
 $ equality sign?

Comment: when you say 4th to 5th, do you mean this: $E \left( y_{t}|F_{t-1}\right) = E \left( \mu_{t}+e_{t}|F_{t-1}\right)$

Comment: Sorry, I couldn't align the equations properly. I meant: $E\left(\mu_{t}\left(\mu_{t}-\mu_{t\mid t-1}\right)\left|F_{t 1}\right.\right)+E\left(\mu_{t}e_{t}\left|F_{t-1}\right.\right) = E\left(\left(\mu_{t}-\mu_{t\mid t-1}\right)^{2}\left|F_{t-1}\right.\right)$.

Comment: I tried to clean it up a little.  Please let me know if this was what you were looking for.  Are you sure about $\eta$ vs. $e$ in the second expression, the one referring to $\mu_{t+1}$ ?